# [Java]: Unable to parse a JSON with no array / sub array in it

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am using the json-simple-1.1.jar
and trying to get multiple (atleast 3) values from the json as shown in the code section.

My code works for a JSON with multiple arrays but not working for simple json format.

```
{
"Addresses": {
    "UserName": "Rahul", 
    "Status": "Active", 
    "CreateDate": "2017-01-09T11:39:31.244Z", 
    "SecretAccessKey": "ABCD-EFGH-HIJK", 
    "AccessKeyId": "1234567"
 }
}
```

Following is the java logic I am trying to use:

```
public static String[] getValuesFromJson(String filename, Object key, int exp_sizeOfArray, String[] exp_keys) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException { 

    String valuesFromJson[] = new String[exp_keys.length]; 

    /** Create a JSONParser object*/
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    /** Read the JSON file using parser*/
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(
            filename));

    System.out.println("JsonObject size: "+jsonObject.keySet().size());
    for (Object object : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get(object.toString()));
    }
    /** Get the values in JSONArray using the key*/
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {

        /** Add the individual set from JSONArray to a JSONObject */
        JSONObject subJsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonArray.get(i).toString());

        /** Check for expected size of array */
        if(subJsonObject.size() <= exp_sizeOfArray){
            int index=0;
            /** Check for each key value in the sub-JSONObject keySet*/
            for (Object object : subJsonObject.keySet()) {

                /** Iterate until the expected key value matches with the actual value*/
                for (int j = 0; j < exp_keys.length; j++) {

                    /** Check if the expected key matches with any of the key value*/
                    if(object.toString().trim().equals(exp_keys[j].toString().trim())){
                        System.out.println("Key: '".concat(object.toString()).concat("'\tValue: '").concat(subJsonObject.get(object)+"'"));
                        valuesFromJson[index] = subJsonObject.get(exp_keys[j]).toString();
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    /** Return the value of expected key*/
    return valuesFromJson;
}
```

I am getting error: "org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray" on below line:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(key);
```

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory. You're trying to read an array where there is none. What is your question?

Comment: If I may ask, why is it that you think there's always an array in your JSON code?

Comment: Well... My previous json format was like: `{ Addresses: [{"One" : "1", "Two" : "2"} {"A" : "Apple", "B":"Ball"}]` So I am considering I was able to fetch those as a JSONArray whn I was creaing the JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`, but there is no array. Rather get all object keys and iterate over it.

If you go to json.org([1](http://json.org)) you can find there:

*An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma)*

Comment: Yes, array is a collection of values, "And not of <key, value>" like hashmap. Actually I am trying to put the values under `JSONObject` to the `JSONArray` to iterate it. Even `jsonObject.keySet()` is giving "Addresses" as the result. :-(

Comment: I got your point about no array in my json. Then how should I fetch the key-value pairs from the JSON? Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: Go one level down. You have object in object.

Answer (score 0):

Voila!
Done it without converting `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(
            filename));
    /** Creating another JSONObject here */
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonObject.get(key).toString());
    for (Object newKey : jsonObject2.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: '".concat(newKey.toString()).concat("'\tValue: '").concat(jsonObject2.get(newKey)+"'"));
    }
```

Thank you guys for the help!